# Need help in extracting value counts from a list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dictionary

I am looking to calculate the % of values against keys from a List of dictionaries and their corresponding counts along with values and their corresponding count using Python.

Used below code to extract keys and their count. Need help in expanding it to extract values and their corresponding count.

The Data looks like this:

```py
people = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "NewYork"},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan"},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "London"},
    {"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "city": "California"},
    {"name": "Lena", "weight": 45, "country": "Italy"},
    {"name": "Ben", "age": 17, "city": "Colombo"},
    {"name": "Lena", "gender": "Female", "country": "Italy"},
    {"name": "Ben", "gender": "Male", "city": "Colombo"},
]


def getKeyCount(lst):
    out = {}
    for d in lst:
        for k in d.keys():
            out[k] = out.get(k, 0) + 1
    return out


def getValCount(lst):
    out = {}
    for d in lst:
        for v in d.values():
            out[v] = out.get(v, 0) + 1
    return out


getKeyCount(people)
# {'name': 8, 'age': 4, 'city': 5, 'country': 3,
# 'hight': 1, 'weight': 1, 'gender': 2}

getValCount(people)
# {'Tom': 2, 'NewYork': 1, 'Mark': 1, 'Japan': 1, 'Pam': 1,
# 'London': 1, 'California': 1, etc.}
```

I want output like this:

```sh
Name: 10
'Tom': 2, 'Mark': 3, 'Pam': 1,'Lena': 3, 'Ben': 2
City:4
'London': 1, 'California': 1, 'NewYork': 2
```

I am new to this, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method on every value to get the count of each value:

```
people = [{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10, "city" : "NewYork"},
          {'name': "Mark", 'age': 5, "country" : "Japan"},
          {'name': "Pam", 'age': 7, "city" : "London"},
          {'name': "Tom", 'hight': 163, "city" : "California"},
          {'name': "Lena", 'weight': 45, "country" : "Italy"},
          {'name': "Ben", 'age': 17, "city" : "Colombo"},
          {'name': "Lena", 'gender': "Female", "country" : "Italy"},
          {'name': "Ben", 'gender': "Male", "city" : "Colombo"}]

def getKeyCount(lst):
    out = {}
    for d in lst:
        for k in d:
            out[k] = out.get(k, []) + [d[k]]
    return out

d = getKeyCount(people)

def display(d, key):
    vals = d[key]
    print("Name:", len(vals))
    print(', '.join(f"{val}: {vals.count(val)}" for val in set(vals)))

display(d, 'name')
display(d, 'city')
```

Output:

```
Name: 8
Mark: 1, Ben: 2, Tom: 2, Pam: 1, Lena: 2
City: 5
London: 1, NewYork: 1, Colombo: 2, California: 1
```

Comment: I have 100s of keys...can loop them some how to get all the results

Comment: @Sherlock You can do: `for key in d: display(d, key)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

people = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "NewYork"},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan"},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "London"},
    {"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "city": "California"},
    {"name": "Lena", "weight": 45, "country": "Italy"},
    {"name": "Ben", "age": 17, "city": "Colombo"},
    {"name": "Lena", "gender": "Female", "country": "Italy"},
    {"name": "Ben", "gender": "Male", "city": "Colombo"},
]

cnt = defaultdict(Counter)
for p in people:
    if not isinstance(p, dict):  # <-- make sure the items are dicts
        continue

    for k, v in p.items():
        cnt[k].update([v])

for k, v in cnt.items():
    print(k, sum(cnt[k].values()))
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(kk, vv), end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

Prints:

```
name 8
Tom: 2 Mark: 1 Pam: 1 Lena: 2 Ben: 2 

age 4
10: 1 5: 1 7: 1 17: 1 

city 5
NewYork: 1 London: 1 California: 1 Colombo: 2 

country 3
Japan: 1 Italy: 2 

hight 1
163: 1 

weight 1
45: 1 

gender 2
Female: 1 Male: 1
```

---

UPDATE: Added check that values are of type `dict`

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' while qpplying it on larger data set

Comment: @Sherlock Make sure that list `people` contains only dictionaries, not strings.

Comment: I have no control over the data...is there any solution to avoid them